# 500 error after running bin/magento setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, aws

I'm working on my first Magento2 site. The site was live and working until I went to install [this CustomShippingPrice](https://marketplace.magento.com/mageside-module-custom-shipping-price.html) extension.

After enabling the module using Magento `module:enable Mageside_CustomShippingPrice` and running the Magento `setup:upgrade command`, the following error start to appear:

Next

```
 Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Invalid block type:
 catalog/product_list_random in
 /var/www/html/store/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:263
```

I have the same code and database running on my local machine without issue following the same steps.

I've tried clearing and flushing the cache and deleting my Magento var/ folder and restarting the web server, same error. I also tried running with the --keep-existing option, no luck.

Reverting the site to a backup prior to running `setup:upgrade` returns the site to normal operation. This leads me to believe the issue is not related to the database.

The web server is an Amazon Linux instance if it matters.

Please help me troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was posting this question, I figured out the issue.

My production instance of the site was a bit older than my local instance.
Turns out deleting my packages and re-running

```
php ./composer.phar install
```

and then following the steps above to install the module fixed the issue.
For some reason running composer.phar update did NOT work.

Hope this helps someone else in troubleshooting.